# ldap_add: no such object (32) while setting up ldap on centos 7?

Tags: centos, openldap

I am setting OpenLDAP on centos7 and seem to encounter an error while adding the first user.

```
[root@web1 ~]# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=web1,dc=com" -f /root/rootuser.ldif
    Enter LDAP Password:
    adding new entry "uid=ldapuser,ou=People,dc=web1,dc=com"
    ldap_add: No such object (32)
            matched DN: dc=web1,dc=com
```

I have added the base.ldif file successfully and need to add the people & group files now.

```
[root@web1 ~]# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=web1,dc=com" -f /root/base.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "dc=web1,dc=com"
ldap_add: Already exists (68)
```

**Base file:**

```
[root@web1 ~]# cat base.ldif
dn: dc=web1,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: web1 com
dc: web1

dn: cn=Manager,dc=web1,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager
Description: Directory Manager

dn: ou=People,dc=web1,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: ou=Group,dc=web1,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group
```

**Rootuser.ldif**

```
[root@web1 ~]# cat rootuser.ldif
dn: uid=ldapuser,ou=People,dc=web1,dc=com
uid: ldapuser
cn: ldapuser
sn: ldapuser
mail: ldapuser@web1.com
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$1$0ck/7MvX$VkTriVqcFOnsoIhF1TzTt1
shadowLastChange: 17223
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1003
gidNumber: 1004
homeDirectory: /home/ldapuser
```

**RootGroup.ldif**

```
[root@web1 ~]# cat rootgroup.ldif
dn: cn=ldapuser,ou=Group,dc=web1,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: ldapuser
userPassword: {crypt}x
gidNumber: 1004
```

**Ldapsearch results for dc**

```
[root@web1 ~]# ldapsearch -hlocalhost -x -sbase | grep '^dn:'
dn: dc=web1,dc=com
```

I am not able to determine what is causing this error.

Comment: Try [`slapcat`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/slapcat8.html) to get a full dump of your LDAP database - seems that `ou=People`is not there. And try `ldapadd` for the base file with option `-c` (continue after error); it seems that after `ldap_add: Already exists (68)` the adding of entries stops.

Comment: Here is the output of slapcat

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxF9oSekI_PwR3ZjRy1uMzlDWDQ/view?usp=sharing]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So please do `ldapadd -c -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=web1,dc=com" -f /root/base.ldif`; this should create the missing `ou`s

Comment: @ridgy This works! Please mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Atul , I tried that  command, but it still gives me the same error: `No such object (32)`. Any suggestions?